# Unwinding from from tableview cell selection in storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my storyboard app, I use a tableview one level up from the root view controller. Through interface builder, I linked my prototype cell to the exit on the root view controller, so a selection of a cell unwinds to the home screen. In my root view I'm connecting it to.

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
}
```

I'm my tableview controller I wasn't doing anything with didSelectRowAtIndexPath but populating some data items, and it was working. I need to implement an accessory on my cells that pushes to a new view, and I did that with newaccessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath and a push segue from my table view using performSegueWithIdentifier. While that works, selecting a cell no longer unwinds to the root view. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm unclear about your problem. You want to be able to perform an unwind  when you select a cell, but go to a new view controller if you touch the accessory button? That should work ok -- make sure you hook up the correct things. For the unwind, make sure you've chosen "Selection Segue" when you make the connection, and for the accessory button, make sure you've chosen "Accessory Action".

Comment: I see, that might be my problem. I'm using selection segue for the unwind, but using a manual segue for the unwind, connected from controller to controller rather than the cell itself. I have two different options for the accessory method, so that's why I'm using performSegueWithIdentifier to distinguish between the two possible view controllers.

Comment: That should work fine, as long as you check for the segue identifier when you do the manual segue.